# API Integration | Benefits of OpenAPI Specification & YAML or JSON File

Tags: json, integration, openapi

My question is probably best aimed at API developers dealing with API integration.

- Do developers gain any benefit for integrating an API (e.g. within a 3rd party application) if they do receive the OpenAPI specification via a YAML- or JSON file?
- Is there a coding advantage of having the actual YAML- or JSON file, which can be directly imported into the IDE compared to a simple access to the OpenAPI documentation (e.g. via SWAGGER UI)?

Potential benefits I could think of could be faster integration or less copy and paste effort from API Portal. Though, I would like to know if that is really the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly subjective question, so perhaps a subjective answer is acceptable. My own personal uses for the OpenAPI file itself:

- run a local mock server so I don't need to hit the main API (possibly incurring costs or inflicting load) while I'm developing
- use my own documentation rendering (I have some accessibility needs, not all API documentation is equal)
- import the OpenAPI into Postman for some quick API exploring
- maybe generate some client/SDK code to get the integration started quickly

In summary, yes, developers benefit greatly from receiving the actual OpenAPI description, and I'd recommend you publish the OpenAPI alongside any API documentation.